# Is there a way to find the sum of the number after the ending of 9?

Tags: python-3.x

The question is:

Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 9 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 9).

> sixty_nine([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) --> 9
>
> sixty_nine([4, 5,7,8, 6, 7, 8, 9,34]) --> it should return -- 58 
>                                             but it returns -- 24(by ignoring 34)

i am not able to understand how to take the sum of numbers after 9

```
arr  = [4, 5,7,8, 6, 7, 8, 9,34]
def sixty_nine(arr):
    sums = 0
    l = len(arr)
    for i in range(l):
         if arr[i] == 6 and 9 in arr[i:]:              
            for j in arr[0:i]:
                sums = sums + j
            return sums


sixty_nine(arr)
```

> t=The output of this program is --- 24

Comment: What about a list such as [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code contains various errors, among them you are returning inside your for-loop which prevents it from traversing the whole list.

I suggest treating this problem in two steps. First write a generator which filters out sublists of the form `[6, ..., 9]`.

Then use `sum` which can sum any iterable, generators included.

```
def ignore_between(lst, a, b):
    i = 0
    while i < len(lst):
        if lst[i] == a:
            try:
                i = lst.index(b, i) + 1
                continue
            except ValueError:
                pass
        yield lst[i]
        i += 1

lst = [4, 5, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8, 9, 34]
output = sum(ignore_between(lst, 6, 9))
print(output) # 58
```